# How to loop over axis plots in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create an axis plot. I was trying to loop over it as I am plotting the same variable for two different categories. Currently, I have written code two times but I am looking for a smarter way with looping, if possible. Any other suggestion will also be helpful.

```
zone = ['AB','CD']
plt.style.use('default')
fig,(ax0,ax1) = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize = (18,18), sharex = False)
i = 0
while i < len(zone):    
    if zone[i] == zone[0]:
        ax0.plot(df0['datetime'], df0['pnl1'], color='k', linewidth=1, label ='PnL1')
        ax0.plot(df0['datetime'], df0['pnl2'], color='m', linewidth=1, label ='PnL2')
        ax00 = ax0.twinx()
        ax00.bar(df0['datetime'], df0['qty'], width = 1/96, color='g', align = 'edge', alpha = 0.5, label ='Qty')
    elif zone[i] == zone[1]:
        ax1.plot(df0['datetime'], df0['pnl1'], color='k', linewidth=1, label ='PnL1')
        ax1.plot(df0['datetime'], df0['pnl2'], color='m', linewidth=1, label ='PnL2')
        ax01 = ax1.twinx()
        ax01.bar(df0['datetime'], df0['hedge'], width = 1/96, color='g', align = 'edge', alpha = 0.5, label ='Qty')
    i = i + 1
```

I want to check if something like below can be done with axis plots or not.

```
zone = ['AB','CD']
plt.style.use('default')
fig,(ax0,ax1) = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize = (18,18), sharex = False)
i = 0
while i < len(zone):    
        ax{''}.format(i).plot(df0['datetime'], df0['pnl1'], color='k', linewidth=1, label ='PnL1')
        ax{''}.format(i).plot(df0['datetime'], df0['pnl2'], color='m', linewidth=1, label ='PnL2')
        ax0{''}.format(i) = ax{''}.format(i).twinx()
        ax0{''}.format(i).bar(df0['datetime'], df0['qty'], width = 1/96, color='g', align = 'edge', alpha = 0.5, label ='Qty')
```

It did not work for me. Any leads to execute axis plot with loop will be helpful.

Comment: Instead of unpacking to ax1, ax2 just pass to axs and address ad axs[0] axs[1] or axs[i] in your loop

Comment: Hello @JodyKlymak
Thank you for getting back quickly. It did work for main axis. However, it did not work when I tried to use it with the twin axis. 

axs0[i] = axs[i].twinx()
axs0[i].bar(df0['datetime'], df0['qty'], width = 1/96, color='g', align = 'edge', alpha = 0.5, label ='qty')

Comment: Some of the examples in the [official reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/demo_constrained_layout.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-demo-constrained-layout-py) may help you.

Comment: I was able to get the desired output.
Instead of defining twin axis explicitly, I used axs[i].twinx().bar(.....................)

Comment: It mostly worked except it messed up the yticks on the secondary y axis when I used below.
`axs[i].twinx().set_ylabel("Qty", fontsize=16, color='black')`

Comment: I don't know what "did not work" means in this context.

Comment: Hi @JodyKlymak
I posted it here with snapshot of my output
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70187108/how-to-adjust-yticks-for-twin-y-axis

Answer (score 2):

Here are some ways:

Simply loop over the list of axes

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig,axes = plt.subplots(2,1)
x = np.linspace(0,5,21)
for ax in axes:
    ax.plot(x,np.sin(x))
plt.show()
```

Works also with index:

```py
for i in range(len(axes)):
    axes[i].plot(x,np.sin(x))
```

For a grid of plot you can use a similar approach:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig,axes = plt.subplots(2,2)
x = np.linspace(0,5,21)
for i in range(len(axes)):
    for j in range(len(axes[0])):
        axes[i][j].plot(x,np.sin(x))
plt.show()
```

If you don't like double-loops, you can flatten the array with [`np.ravel()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html)

```py
fig,axes = plt.subplots(2,2)
x = np.linspace(0,5,21)
for ax in np.ravel(axes):
    ax.plot(x,np.sin(x))
plt.show()
```